# Why doesn't my computer see all USB devices (27 3G modems)?

Tags: windows, port, usb-hub

I have a (Dell) laptop with 3 USB ports.

There are two USB hubs connected (13 ports each, hubs are powered by external electric source); so in total there are 27 USB ports (13+13+1).

Each port has a 3G modem connected to it (CDMA USB devices).

When I go to My Computer after that - I see 11 connected devices.

When I run my own program that does some work with the modems - it can see 20.

But there are 27.

I don't get it.  Why can't I, and how can I, access to all 27 devices?

Comment: Can't really see this being a programming question. Voting for migration.

Comment: I have one guess: maybe once windows shows "Disk Z" - it runs out of letters for devices, so it doesn't recognize them?

Comment: Why would a 3G modem show up in "My Computer" at all?  Do they all show up in Windows' Device Manager?

Comment: I would bring up Windows' Device Manager and check for problems.